# Chinese word well illustrated graphically

Tags: characters, simplified-characters

i am working on an interactive dictionary with common Chinese characters.
I found the word 乒乓   pīngpāng, the Chinese word for ping-pong (table tennis).
I consider the graphic of the association of these two characters is very well linked to the object.
Are there any others similar Chinese words as well illustrated as that one, by the chosen characters ?

Comment: You do know a percentage of Chinese characters are  hieroglyph/ pictogram (象形文字) , right? Most of them are simple nouns, the less evolved a character the more it looks like an illustration of the object it depicts

https://www.zdic.net/

Comment: Thanks :-) i know, but i am not interested by single characters. 乒 pīng  and 乓 pāng are different characters, with different meanings but their association in the word 乒乓 makes graphically sens. Maybe other words like that  one ?

Answer (score 3):

- an area with many trees is called a 森林
- something pointy (small on one end, big on the other) is called 尖
- something that isn't right is called 歪
- small pieces of dirt are called 尘
- a string going through several things is 串

Comment: The word  森林  sēnlín  is by the words i am looking for :-)  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

All I can think of off the top of my head:

牛羊: cattle (see the cow and goat face)

凹凸: bumps

The similarity between words and objects are most likely coincidental.

Comment: +1 for 凹凸: bumps

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a subset of Chinese characters with meaningful construction.

The classification of Chinese characters can be summarized with 六書 (Six ways of writing):

[Wikipedia - Chinese character classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification)

- **象形: pictograms** e.g. 日 (sun)
- **指事: simple ideograms** e.g. 一 (one), 上 (up) 下 (down)
- 形聲: phono-semantic compound
- **會意: compound ideograms** e.g. 信 (trust) from 人 (person) + 言 (speech)
- 轉注: derivative cognates
- 假借: rebus (phonetic loan)

Comment: no :-)   i am not looking for these hanzi, only words...

Comment: @faure My answer implies you could look up characters belonging to these methods of construct. There are too many to list, so you could pick the ones you like on your own. Most single characters in Chinese may be classified as "words", but there are still words which consist of multiple syllables.

Comment: [一一](https://youdao.com/w/一一) and [上下](https://youdao.com/w/上下) and [人人](https://youdao.com/w/人人) and [日日](https://youdao.com/w/日日) are words.

Answer (score 1):

A notable one is:

> 囧 （jiong3）

(and its alternative form 冏) which is used as a "sad face" emoticon. It must be noted that the original meaning of the character according to [Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%9B%A7) is 光明。
The "sad face" meaning is an informal usage developed in online chat and texts.